# `cd` in script refuses to actually cd, shows no error

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

I'm running a script which, when accepting a specific argument, should change the running directory.

However, despite showing no error at all (and the directory being accessible with regular `cd`), the directory does not actually change.

What I'm expecting is - if I run the script with the `cd` argument (for example: `potato.sh cd`, it should `cd` to a path set in the script beforehand (ex: `/tmp`).

This is the code:

```
if [[ $1 == 'cd' ]]; then
        DIR="/tmp"
        if [[ -n "$DIR" ]]; then
                echo "$DIR" #This is set beforehand, but moved here for the sake of the example
                cd "$DIR"
                if [[ $? == "0" ]]; then
                        echo "Hurray!"
                        exit 0
                else
                        echo "Oh, no!"
                        exit 1
                fi
        else
                echo -e "Could not find ${RED}$DIR${STOP}. Sorry!"
        fi
fi
```

When run (`potato.sh cd`), the script will correctly output the directory I set (`/tmp`), and echo `Hurray!`, but won't actually change the directory.

Many similar scripts have worked for me before. Would love your advice on what I'm missing...

Thanks!